# Can't delete shared folder from "File Explorer" but can using rmdir in cmd shell

Tags: windows-10, permissions, windows-explorer, active-directory, user-folders

this is driving me nuts and can't figure out why it's happening and hope you can help me:

I have a computer running Windows 10 Pro (v1809) that belongs to a small AD domain at home.  I have a security group `OD` defined with two users in it, `M` and `F`. `M` owns a directory tree in the computer but all files and folders have all permissions are set to Allow for `OD` and they're inherited to all the objects in the directory.

`F` can read, edit and delete any file in the directory.  `F` can also create new directories and rename existing ones, *but* it can't delete any existing directory when navigating with File Explorer. I select the directory, press DEL, nothing, not even an error message; select the directory, right-click and select Delete, nothing again; select directory, press Shit+Del, same result. `F` is even and administrator of the computer and it doesn't matter if the folder is empty or not.

*Now*, if I open a cmd prompt window (standard, not even RunAs: Administrator), cd to the parent directory and use RMDIR, it works, the folder gets deleted without problem.  Does anybody know why I can't delete the folders using File Explorer but can via prompt?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Haven't found a solution yet but discovered another behavior: this folder is marked as shared and if I open it on a different computer using the same account I'm using when login-in locally, I can delete it! Makes no sense ;-(

Comment: Did you attempt to edit your question while not logged in?